# Popcorn constructor syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, popcornjs

Any idea why this is not firing autoplay? It's my first time using this plugin but I thought I had the syntax right...?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script src="support/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="support/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready( function() {

        var popClip = Popcorn("#sampleClip", {
            autoplay: true
        });

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <video id="sampleClip">
        <source src="..sample.mp4">
        <source src="..sample.ogv">
        <source src="..sample.webm">    
    </video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any `autoplay` property. I do see the `autoplay()` method here: http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/media-methods/#autoplay

Comment: indeed, the format I've used is for setting properties only maybe, not for calling methods on the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using autoplay as a `method`instead of a `flag`. The documentation is not very clear about using it as a flag. As a method I'm totally sure it works, as you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/popcornjs/b7C8C/).

```
$(document).ready( function() {

        var popClip = Popcorn("#sampleClip");
        popClip.autoplay();
});
```

Besides, make sure jQuery and popcorn were actually loaded. I'm also not sure that `..sample.mp4` is actually going to work as a source. Try replacing them by something formatted like this: `../sample.mp4`.

Comment: `popClip.autoplay( true );` did it. thanks. As you said maybe `flag` is no go